# MemoryStream to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, memorystream, bitmapimage, tessnet2, magick.net

I am having a bit of a hard time converting `MemoryStream` into `BitmapImage`.  There are a lot of questions on `SO` regarding similar situations, but after trying everything on them, I've been unable to fix this, so I turn to you.  Note that I'm working with `Magick.NET` (ImageMagick.NET) and `Tessnet2` -- that is what some of that code is.

I use `Bitmap` class to do most of the work in Magick.NET and Tessnet2.  `BitmapImage` is used for displaying purposes.

First, I load up the PDF and extract a cropped bitmap from its first page:

```
public Task PdfToBmp(string path)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var image = new MagickImage())
        {
            MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory("./");

            var settings = new MagickReadSettings
            {
                Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300),
                FrameCount = 1
            };

            image.Read(path, settings);
            image.Crop(new MagickGeometry(1850, 200, 600, 140));

            // ImageStream is a MemoryStream property.
            ImageStream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Write(ImageStream, MagickFormat.Bmp);
            ImageStream.Position = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

That is when I save the bitmap into the `MemoryStream`.  Once I have `MemoryStream` loaded up, I move onto working with it.  I instantiate a `Bitmap`, so that I may use it for `Tessnet2` related work and then try to instantiate a `BitmapImage`.

```
public Task DoOcr()
{
    if (ImageStream == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    TargetImage = new Bitmap(ImageStream);
    ImageStream.Position = 0;

    // ----------------------- Problem Area ----------------------- //
    DisplayImage = new BitmapImage();
    DisplayImage.BeginInit();
    DisplayImage.StreamSource = ImageStream;
    DisplayImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    DisplayImage.EndInit();

    //ImageStream.Close();
    // ------------------------------------------------------------ //

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var ocr = new Tesseract();
        ocr.Init("tessdata", "eng", false);
        var results = ocr.DoOCR(TargetImage, Rectangle.Empty);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Results = new ObservableCollection<Word>(results);
        });
    });
}
```

This is where I'm having a problem.  Without that `DisplayImage` block, the program runs fine and I just don't get the displayed image.  I'm even able to save the `Bitmap` (`TargetImage`) to a file with no problems.  However, with the `DisplayImage` block, I get `System.NullReferenceException`:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
_HResult=-2147467261
_message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
HResult=-2147467261
IsTransient=false
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=System
StackTrace:
     at System.Uri.CreateThisFromUri(Uri otherUri)
InnerException:
```

I'm unable to pinpoint where it occurs exactly, because the `ImageStream` object looks "fine" upon inspection.  It contains data and is at position 0.  If I try to close it, or do anything with it, after assigning it as the `StreamSource` to `DisplayImage`, I get a `null` exception on the line that attempts to perform such action.  I even tried creating two different streams, to see if that's the problem; however, I was getting the exact same behavior.  Debugging this is kind of a pain, considering it doesn't point to any one specific line.  There's obviously an issue between this `MemoryStream` and `BitmapImage`.  Could it be possible that there's some sort of format/conversion problem between the two, but not between `MemoryStream` and `Bitmap` in this particular situation?

I tried the file route, where I save `MagickImage` to a file and load it up into `BitmapImage` through `Uri` and it worked flawlessly; however, I would like to be able to perform this in-memory.  By the way, setting position to `0` on the MemoryStream did not seem to affect either `Bitmap` (loads properly) or `BitmapImage` (same exception).

The temporary fix I currently use is to make `DisplayImage` a `BitmapSource`, rather than `BitmapImage`:

```
DisplayImage = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    TargetImage.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
    BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(TargetImage.Width, TargetImage.Height));
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote and the vote to close?  You're not being very helpful.

Comment: use, 

Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(memoryStreamHere);

Assuming the memory stream is actually a bitmap image.

Comment: @Ryios I don't have a problem getting `Bitmap` to work.  My problem is `BitmapImage`.

Answer (score 0):

The Magick.NET's `Write()` method has some bugs, so we have to use `ToBitmap()`.

```
image.ToBitmap().Save(ImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```